# SpringBoot application.properties file with multiple users/passwords/roles

Tags: spring-boot

I know I can set up my user, password and roles in springboot using application.properties file like:

```
spring.security.user.name=myuser
spring.security.user.password=mypass
spring.security.user.roles=myrole
```

However, what if my application has multiple users who can access it?

How do I set multiple user names/passwords/roles in application.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure you application programmatically:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("myuser")
            .password("mypass")
            .roles("myrole")
            .and()
            .withUser("myuser2")
            .password("{noop}mypass2")
            .roles("myrole2");
    }
}
```

This `@Configuration` allow you to declare multiple users anyway if you don't want to use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`you can do:

```java
@Bean
public UserDetailsService users() {
    UserDetails user1 = User.builder()
        .username("myuser")
        .password("mypass")
        .roles("myrole")
        .build();
    UserDetails user2 = User.builder()
        .username("myuser2")
        .password("{noop}mypass2")
        .roles("myrole2")
        .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2);
}
```

**Pay Attention:** {noop} mean that password is not encrypted. If you want to use encryption you must declare it. For example using {bcrypt}

### **Only for demonstration purposes**

If you want store all users, passwords and roles in application.properties you can map the values in List as follow:

application.properties:

```java
security.users=user1,user2
security.passwords=password1,password2
security.roles=role1,role1
```

Map properties to lists:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security")
public class Properties {
    private List<String> users;
    private List<String> passwords;
    private List<String> roles;

    ...
    //getter and setters
}
```

Wherever you want you can take properties using `@Autowired`

```java
@Autowired 
private Properties properties;
```

You can iterate on list to take values.

**Disclaimer**: This is really bad solution. It is not secure and you should not implement in production env.

Comment: Thanks but these are hardcoded values you have there in configure()  method.  I am trying to avoid that and have these in application.properties file, then read in configure method using @Value or Environment.getProperty and used like you use it above.

Comment: If you want you can use list of value in application.properties. for example `users=user1,user2` can be mapped into List<String>. If you use same position for username and password you can easy handle that and use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`or `UserDetailsService`. Sure it 's not the best solution but it can work

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I am trying to figure out but I am not able to get it to work.  Would you be able to provide example for multiple user names, passwords, roles in application.properties?  Thanks again

Comment: I answered to give you an example but this is a very bad solution. You should not use the application.properties file for these purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to sore all users in application.properties? If you have multiple users you can create a users table in your database that correspond to user entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String password;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

Then you create UserRepository interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Implement UserDetails:

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {
    private User user;

    public UserDetailsImpl(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    //...
}
```

Create MyUserDetailsService:

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
    return new UserDetailsImpl(user);
}
```

}

In your CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter you add:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }
    }
```

Then you can save a user in the database and login.

Comment: I assume you are calling c-tor in UserDetailsImpl by mistake MyUserPrincipal?

Comment: I think same issue is in MyUserDetailsService.  Could you elaborate what is UserDetailsImpl supposed to do?  I dont see it being used in your code snippets?

Comment: I just edited the code snippet. loadUserByUsername method has to return UserDetailsImpl.

Comment: You can use this tutorial : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database